# Is a vehicle still a vehicle if it's no longer an artifact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's pretend I have a vehicle (say, [Smuggler's Copter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSmuggler%27s%5d%2b%5bCopter%5d)) enchanted with a [Siege Modification](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSiege%20Modification%5d). This vehicle creature has not been crewed this turn. I also control a [Neurok Transmuter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNeurok%20Transmuter%5d) and activate the second ability of the Transmuter, targeting the Copter.

The Copter is a creature due to the Modification.

> As long as enchanted permanent is a Vehicle, it’s a creature in addition to its other types.

The Transmuter takes being an artifact away.

> Until end of turn, target artifact creature becomes blue and isn’t an artifact.

Is the Copter still have the Vehicle type and therefore is a 6/3 blue creature? Or does not being an artifact mean not being a Vehicle, and therefore, the Copter is a blue permanent with no types, and the Modification falls off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Smuggler's Copter will stop being a vehicle and a creature, and the Siege Modification will fall off.

[Rule 205.3g](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Type_line) says

> Artifacts have their own unique set of subtypes; these subtypes are called artifact types. The artifact types are Clue, Contraption, Equipment (see rule 301.5), Fortification (see rule 301.6), Treasure, and **Vehicle** (see rule 301.7).

And rule 205.1a says

> Some effects set an object’s card type. In such cases, the new card type(s) replaces any existing card types. Counters, effects, and damage marked on the object remain with it, even if they are meaningless to the new card type. Similarly, when an effect sets one or more of an object’s subtypes, the new subtype(s) replaces any existing subtypes from the appropriate set (creature types, land types, artifact types, enchantment types, planeswalker types, or spell types). **If an object’s card type is removed, the subtypes correlated with that card type will remain if they are also the subtypes of a card type the object currently has; otherwise, they are also removed for the entire time the object’s card type is removed.** Removing an object’s subtype doesn’t affect its card types at all.

Once the artifact type is removed from the Smuggler's Copter, the vehicle subtype is no longer correlated with any of its remaining types, so the Vehicle subtype is removed for as long as the artifact type is removed. This means that Siege Modification's ability that makes the Copter a creature is no longer active, so it will also not be a creature. Since it is at that point neither a creature nor a vehicle, Siege Modification is not legally attached to it, so Siege Modification will go to the graveyard. Smuggler's Copter ends up as a typeless blue permanent.

Comment: If instead of Siege Modification, the Copter had just had its crew ability used; then it would still be a regular creature until end of turn after no longer being an artifact, correct?

Comment: That is correct. The specific outcome here is caused is caused by the fact that Siege Modification's ability is conditional.

Comment: That said, you can still activate the vehicle's Crew ability even though it's already a creature. (It can even crew itself if you're really desperate).  That will keep Seige Modification from falling off until end of turn when the Vehicle returns to being an artifact.

Comment: "the subtypes correlated with that card type will remain if they are also the subtypes of a card type the object currently has" Are there any subtypes that 'belong' to multiple card types?

Comment: The creature and tribal types have the same set of subtypes. The same is true of the instant and sorcery types.

Comment: I think the answer is missing one detail: the Modification effect depends (613.7) on the Transmuter effect. If they were simply applied in timestamp order the Copter would be a nonartifact creature, wouldn't it?

Comment: You're right, 613.7 does apply here, but that gets into the weedy details of the interaction. When you make the distinction between timestamp ordering and dependency ordering, you seem to be taking the perspective of someone who is aware of a large fraction of the "Interaction of Continuous Effects" rules, but not the specific rule about dependencies. Overall, those rules are written to work in intuitive ways, so I don't think they're necessary to quote when the interaction makes sense without them.

Comment: While this specific answer is correct in regards to the question asked. Isn't the specific example of Siege Modification falling off the Creature'd Smuggler's Copter incorrect? Siege Modification can enchant a vehicle or *Creature*, and auras do not require you to announce which type it's being attached to. If either qualification is true Creature or Vehicle: Siege Modification stays right where it is.

Comment: I've edited the first sentence. Does that resolve that issue for you?